# In Python, generate a random path for the TSP according to transition probabilities

Tags: python, random, probability, transition, traveling-salesman

For the travelling salesman problem (TSP), I would like to generate in Python a random tour (where each node from a set of n is visited only once) from a state-transition matrix M (n x n), for which M[i,j] contains the probability that the shortest global path connects node i to node j.

Anyone knows how to do that in Python? I'm asking here about general methods or modules that do that.

Example: suppose that M[i,j]=1 for j=(i+1)%n and 0 elsewhere. All the paths that would be generated (always starting from 0) are: (0,1,2,...,n). If you slightly change this matrix, substituting the 1.0 for 0.9 and putting 0.1 at M[i,i+2], a possible path is: (0,2,3,..,n,1). In this particular example where some probabilities are 0, I know that the last move is impossible (from node n to node 1) and for that reason you can assume that probabilities are always greater than 0.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the negative votes, it's ok to downvote but could you explain the reason? Is it because it's not the good place for such a question?

Comment: Is this a question about sampling? Is it that you are trying to generate a random path with probability that it is the shortest global path, such that you are more likely to generate 'good' solutions?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I edited my question to add an example.

Comment: Ok so the graph is always fully connected, but the question remains - do you want the product of the individual probabilities to be proportional to the probability that the path is generated?

Comment: I want to narrow the search, by limiting it to k of these paths (hopefully if probabilities are good these paths would be good candidates for the shortest path). The probabilities here are given. I don't know if it answers your question.

Comment: Well you can do a greedy forward sampling if you like. If your vertex set is S Start at vertex a: Go to vertex i with $P_ai / Sum_i P_aj $ for i in S - a , and recursively repeat. Does this help?

Comment: Yes. It is the first solution I was thinking about. Thank you @user3684792.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(It would have been a much better question if you provided a bit of code; especially because the question is targeting a step which has many steps before)

Here is some approach which should be only taken as some idea as the setup might be a bit annoying (cvxpy and some MIP-solver which is not bad; i'm using CBC here, see cvxpy's docs for alternatives or setup-docs). It's also not really tested. The idea is somewhat based on MAP-calculation in Probabilistic graphical models, but the transfer might be mathematically wrong (no guarantees). It's also harder as the opt-problem in our case is bound to constraints!

### Idea

Formulate an optimization-problem maximizing the a-priori-probabilities used = part of solution-path (and square this = bigger deviations are more heavily penalized), while generating a valid solution (valid path).

While the problem might be non-convex (i'm not sure) and therefore infeasible to solve in a globally-optimal way), we are using some well-analyzed heuristic for *difference of convex programming here*.

**Remark:** This approach is by design searching for the global-optimum (not entirely true as we are using nonconvex-optimization algorithms). This means, that multiple samplings with different solutions is not really natural within this approach (but calling the DCCP routine with different starting-points will result in different solutions with high probability).

**Remark 2:** Performance is very bad for non-small instances (with non-commercial solvers) which renders it a more theoretical-approach.

### Implementation

Here is some implementation using Python 3, numpy, scipy (shortest paths), cvxpy (opt-problem formulation) and dccp (difference of convex function optimization extension for cvxpy)

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import csgraph_from_dense, shortest_path
from scipy.spatial import distance
from cvxpy import *
import dccp
np.random.seed(1)

""" Create random problem """
N = 10
distances = np.random.rand(N, N)                    # assymetric

""" Calculate shortest paths """
csparse_distances = csgraph_from_dense(distances)
shortest = shortest_path(csparse_distances)         # directed

""" Calculate a-prori probabilities based on global shortest paths """
shortest_global = np.copy(shortest)
for row in range(shortest_global.shape[0]):
    # normalize sum to 1
    row_sum = np.sum(shortest_global[row, :])
    shortest_global[row, :] /= row_sum

""" Formulate MIQP problem """
# Based on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem
#       and my example here: https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/blob/master/examples/tsp_mip.py#L16

# Variables
x = Bool(N, N)                                      # edge x,y in PATH
u = Int(N)                                          # aux-var

# Constraints
constraints = []

for j in range(N):                                      # ingoing: exactly 1
    indices = list(range(0, j)) + list(range(j + 1, N))
    constraints.append(sum_entries(x[indices, j]) == 1)
for i in range(N):
    indices = list(range(0, i)) + list(range(i + 1, N)) # outgoing: exactly 1
    constraints.append(sum_entries(x[i, indices]) == 1)

for i in range(1, N):                               # subtour-elimination
    for j in range(1, N):
        if i != j:
            constraints.append(u[i] - u[j] + N*x[i, j] <= N-1)

# Objective
obj = Maximize(sum_entries(square(mul_elemwise(shortest_global, x))))

# Solve
prob = Problem(obj, constraints)
print("problem is DCP: ", prob.is_dcp())
prob.solve(method='dccp', solver=CBC, ccp_times=10)  # do not use default solver!
# Remark: formulation above not accepted by CVX-ruleset
#         -> need "difference of convex function"-extension
#         -> heuristic (which is well-known for good behaviour)!


""" Print solution """
print('Solution path matrix')
print(np.round(x.value).astype('int'))
print('A-priori probability matrix')
print(np.round(shortest_global, 2))
```

#### Output

```
...
...
iteration= 1 cost value =  0.34508891154470694 tau =  0.005
iteration= 2 cost value =  0.5092119781611304 tau =  0.006
iteration= 3 cost value =  0.5092119781611304 tau =  0.0072
Solution path matrix
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
A-priori probability matrix
[[ 0.    0.14  0.    0.24  0.11  0.07  0.07  0.03  0.13  0.21]
 [ 0.12  0.    0.09  0.22  0.01  0.17  0.13  0.11  0.06  0.07]
 [ 0.11  0.1   0.    0.27  0.08  0.12  0.05  0.02  0.1   0.15]
 [ 0.06  0.17  0.06  0.    0.15  0.12  0.11  0.09  0.01  0.23]
 [ 0.09  0.16  0.09  0.18  0.    0.13  0.13  0.11  0.05  0.05]
 [ 0.01  0.15  0.02  0.21  0.12  0.    0.08  0.05  0.15  0.22]
 [ 0.06  0.17  0.06  0.25  0.03  0.12  0.    0.09  0.11  0.11]
 [ 0.09  0.07  0.07  0.21  0.08  0.08  0.11  0.    0.14  0.15]
 [ 0.11  0.16  0.11  0.09  0.07  0.14  0.11  0.12  0.    0.1 ]
 [ 0.07  0.17  0.07  0.21  0.15  0.12  0.12  0.09  0.    0.  ]]
```

**Edit:**

- Ouch, somehow ECOS_BB seems to be still used which tells us there is much more potential with a better solver-setup.

Comment: Wow. Thank you sascha. I will take the time to study your answer. At first glance I'm not sure to understand why sampling from a given distribution needs optimization but maybe I miss something.

Comment: @Patrick You don't need to (**idea: which possible realization is the most probable given the transition-probabilities under the constraints given**). But the idea comes from MAP-approximation in PGMs (at least how i see this). The problem is though, that we need valid solutions and basic-MAP approximation is unconstrained-optimization which is much much easier. Don't get your hopes to high! (Maybe also check some literature on: "Sampling from combinatoric structures". But i fear it's an complex topic)